# Replace spider with list when multiple icons are at the same location

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

In Google Earth if I have multiple icons that appear in the same location and you click on it, it results in a spider.  I would like to override this with a list instead that stays static until you close it.

How would I go about creating this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do your own custom clustering, since Earth doesn't expose to you any information about that spider cluster in the API. You'd want, perhaps, to look at the [MarkerClusterer utility library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) for inspiration, but the code is Maps specific, not Earth.